# A red icon appears in place of the app icon in notifications

Tags: ios, ipad, uilocalnotification

The app that I'm currently working on allows users to set reminders.

This shows up as notifications on the iPad/iPad simulator. Everything is fine, except for the icon of the app that is next to the notification. Its always red, although I have given an image for the app icon.

Ex: in the image, the calendar and reminder app icons are visible. How do I go about doing the same.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you have included a screenshot that actually shows the problem?

Comment: Do you have an Icon-Small-50 image?

Comment: @jrturton I wanted to, but dont have access to the device now and in the simulator it only comes as a alertview and not in the notifications bar.

Comment: @neilvillareal dont think so. Do I need to add one explicitly.

Comment: @Vittal That's the only reason I can think of why the home screen icon is different from the notification area icon. Although I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red icon is the icon Apple uses in its sample projects. You probably forgot to change the Icon-Small-50 image in your bundle. This would explain how this red icon only appears in the Notification Center.